# How to save an image in pims?

Tags: python, python-3.x, trackpy

I am trying to save one frame in a video. The video was opened using pims. My script goes like this:

```
import pims
frames = pims.ND2_Reader('sample directory/file.nd2')
image = frames[123]
image.savefig('sample directory/file.png')
```

Then I received an error message say "'Frame' object has no attribute 'savefig'". How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentations, PIMS returns images as Frame objects, and Frames can be treated precisely the same as numpy arrays. This is same in [ND2_Reader](https://github.com/soft-matter/pims_nd2/blob/master/pims_nd2/nd2reader.py#L12). And numpy arrays do not have such function called "savefig".

To save images, you can use the package [PyAv](http://mikeboers.github.io/PyAV/) mentioned in the documentation, Or simply use **Opencv** utilities which

```
import cv2
cv2.imwrite('sample directory/file.png', frame)
```

Or **scipy** utilities.